# CFNetwork HTTP timeout?

Tags: iphone, http, macos, core-foundation, cfhttp

I am looking for a way to add a timeout to a CFHTTP request. It seems like there should be a feature of the `CFHTTPMessage` or the `CFReadStream` object, but I can't find it. Do I have to roll my own timer on the run loop or something? (if so, any code for this?)

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

My answer is outdated but I can't delete the accepted answer.

Comment: Roger, I did look @ ASIHTTPRequest and it looks great, except there's one thing I need it to do that it doesn't -- which is stream data from a CFReadStream object. (I could add a patch I s'pose...)

Comment: You should drop Ben at All seeing eye a line. He answers his mail and is a nice guy. If you have a patch, I'm sure he'd take it.

Comment: ASIHTTPRequest does use an NSInputStream for the request body when posting files from an ASIFormDataRequest, and also whenever shouldStreamPostDataFromDisk is true.

If your CFReadStream is reading from a file on disk, just use setPostBodyFilePath: and it'll do the rest. If not, it shouldn't be too tough to patch it to use your CFReadStream instead, but drop me a msg (my email is on the website) if you need a hand.

Comment: Thanks for the offer -- I ended up using NSURLConnection for everything except the POST, which I augmented with a NSTimer. Kind of a cop-out but I already had the code and some unit tests :P Next time I will start with ASIHTTPRequest in the first place!

Comment: Just FYI, I finally got around to extending ASIHTTPRequest and it was quite simply to make it take a stream instead of file or buffer. I used `socketpair()` to make a write stream that could be written from a different thread. Let me know if you are interested in code. Thanks :)

Comment: This is not a suggestion topic, it's a concrete question.

Comment: @Andy - don't understand your comment. Seems like ASI... was the answer to sehugg's question.

Answer (score 2):

Try this, readStream is your CFReadStreamRef:

```
#define _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout CFSTR("_kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout")

double to = 15; // 15s timeout
CFNumberRef num = CFNumberCreate(kCFAllocatorDefault, kCFNumberDoubleType, &to);
CFReadStreamSetProperty(readStream, _kCFStreamPropertyReadTimeout, num);
CFRelease(num);
```

Constant for write timeout is _kCFStreamPropertyWriteTimeout