# iPhone. How to Track Progress of HTTP Upload

Tags: iphone, file-upload

could you please advice how to track progress of file upload to HTTP Server?

I am using NSURLConnection and other classes to solve the task of file upload.
But I cann't find out how to track upload progress.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked something similar awhile back:

[CFNetwork HTTP timeout?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/962076/cfnetwork-http-timeout)

I don't know if ASIHTTPRequest has this support built-in yet, and I didn't have a reason back then to switch over, but you may want to check it out and/or contact the authors.